# The configuration section 'system.webserver' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: xml, iis

Web.config file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        </httpErrors>
      </system.webServer>
      <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
      <trace enabled="true" >
      </trace>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
      <compilation debug="false" />
      <authentication>
          <forms cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" protection="Validation" />
      </authentication>
      <sessionState cookieless="UseUri" mode="StateServer" />s
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Error message when running Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/' -filter "system.webServer/httpErrors" -name "errorMode" command in powershell:

Get-WebConfigurationProperty : Filename: \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

Line number: 4

Error: The configuration section 'system.webserver' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root cause is you are placing`<system.webserver>` inside`<system.web>`. Please  modify these attribute because system.webserver and system.web are in the same level.

Please modify the configuration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

      <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        </httpErrors>
      </system.webServer>

 <system.web>
      <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
      <trace enabled="true" >
      </trace>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
      <compilation debug="false" />
      <authentication>
          <forms cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" protection="Validation" />
      </authentication>
      <sessionState cookieless="UseUri" mode="StateServer" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please remember to remove "s" here
[image]